# Reading data from System.IO.Stream to text or a file

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, memorystream

I am using HttpWebRequest.GetStreamData() to get data from stream and then writing a couple of files in that variable.
Before calling the GetResponse() method on the stream, I need to get the copy of data and put it in text format.
Here's my code snippet

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            wr.Method = "POST";

         string requestbody = "Some Body Text"

            Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();
            foreach (fragment in Documents).ToList())
            {
                        byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestbody);
                        rs.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);

                        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fragment.FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                        int bytesRead = 0;
                        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                        {
                            rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                        fileStream.Flush();
                        fileStream.Close();
                        fileStream = null;
                        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Trailer Text");
                        rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);

                    }
                }

           using (StreamReader strm = new StreamReader(rs))
        {
            string text = strm.ReadToEnd();
        }

            rs.Close();
            rs = null;
```

The issue is I get error "stream was not readable".
When I check the property rs.canread, it is set to false.

Can anyone help me reading the content of my rs stream.
I have tried a couple of methods but none seems to be working as of now.

Comment: what is Documents and where is it defined?

Comment: Documents are a bunch of pdf documents that I need to send and its defined somewhere else in the code. that part is anyways working fine.

Comment: That is because rs is the request (upload) stream which you can only write into. Are you trying to read the web server response? Then invoke `Stream responseStream = wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();`

Comment: No, I want to read the stream before I invoke the webResponse. Is there any way to read from this stream before calling in for the response?

Comment: Oh. Then just fill a memory stream or a file stream (a temporary file) first. I know this is not an efficient way, but what you want to achieve requires this. When you are done, use `myTempStream.Position = 0; myTempStream.CopyTo(rs);`

Comment: Then you will be able to read the contents you are sending to the web server using the myTempStream. (Don't forget to reset the position of the stream to zero first)

Comment: Oguz Ozgul:   Yea..I was thinking of the same thing just now. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.